# Scheme : I have no idea to implement given function

Tags: scheme

It's the exercise of "Programming language pragmatics, Michael Scott" .

Q. return a list containing all elements of a given list that satisfy a given predicate. For example, (filter (lambda (x) (< x 5) '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7)) should return (3 2 4).

I think that question require function which satisfy every predicate not only above. But I don't have any idea to implement such function. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) procedure already exists in most Scheme implementations, it behaves as expected:

```
(filter (lambda (x) (< x 5)) '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7))
=> '(3 2 4)
```

Now, if the question is *how* to implement it, it's rather simple - I'll give you some hints so you can write it by yourself. The trick here is noticing that the procedure is receiving another procedure as parameter, a *predicate* in the sense that it'll return `#t` or `#f` when applied to each of the elements in the input list. Those that evaluate to `#t` are kept in the output list, those that evaluate to `#f` are discarded. Here's the skeleton of the solution, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (filter pred? lst)
  (cond (<???>       ; if the list is empty
         <???>)      ; return the empty list
        (<???>       ; apply pred? on the first element, if it's #t
         (cons <???> ; then cons the first element
               (filter pred? <???>))) ; and advance recursion
        (else (filter pred? <???>)))) ; else just advance recursion
```

Comment: (define (filter pred? lst) //
  (cond  //
    ((null? lst) '())  //
    (#t (apply   //
    (cons  //
I do like this, but I don't know how to apply pred? on the first element (sorry but i don't know how to linebreak when add comment)

Comment: A synonym of apply: _call_ it. The predicate it's just a procedure, like any other - call it passing the first element of the list as its argument

Comment: Lopez Then (filter pred? (car lst)) like this? Actually I don't understand clearly after 4th line.

Comment: 4th line: `cons` the result of calling the predicate on the first element of the list, with the result of advancing the recursion. This is the standard way to build an output list, I'd recommend you take a look at either "How to Design Programs" or "The Little Schemer", it's a fundamental ability that you need to understand when learning Scheme.

Comment: Notice that in your last comment you're not calling the predicate. How do we call a procedure, let's say, `f` with an argument, let's say `x`? like this: `(f x)`

Comment: Then..just (pred? (car lst)) is right? I'm really confused using scheme with just online manual.

Comment: How about previous line?(before cons) "apply pred? on the first element" is just pred?

Comment: sorry, I seem to have confused the line numbers :( . Let's go through it all over again: in the line before the `cons` call the predicate, to see if it's true for the first element. If it is true, in the line with the `cons` put the first element, and in the next two lines just advance to the rest of the list.

Comment: then ((pred? (car lst)) and (cons (car lst)) (filter pred? (cdr lst))) and (else (filter pred? (cdr lst))))) is right?

Comment: Phew! I'm glad to hear that. And I repeat my advice: you need to learn  how to structure the solution to recursive problems using Scheme, The Little Schemer and/or How to Design Programs will be very, very useful for this

Comment: Yes, I have to find those two. It's too hard.