# Define a function in Racket taking a list of numbers

Tags: racket

I need to define a function (threshold) that can't use the filter function that takes a list of numbers and another number and outputs elements strictly less than. For example:

```
    > (threshold '(3 6.2 7 2 9 5.3 1) 6)
    '(3 2 5.3 1)
```

I was thinking of defining a less than function but i don't know where to begin I came across this but I don't understand what pred does exactly. Can someone explain to me?

```
  (define (threshold pred lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) null)
      ((pred (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (threshold pred (rest lst))))
    (else (threshold pred (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869018/scheme-i-have-no-idea-to-implement-given-function

Comment: Could you please be more precise in saying what you are not understanding about "pred"? By the way, the pred name stands for "predicate" -- a function that takes a value and returns true or false as an answer.